# I'm unable to login any suggestions, both in case of stored procedure and codebehind

Tags: c#, sql

```
CREATE TABLE MYUSE100(userid number,username varchar2(45),ppassword varchar2(50));
insert into MYUSE200 values('harry','potter');
```

here is my stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure  p_myuse200(p_username1 in  varchar2,p_password1 in varchar2,v_count out number)
AS
BEGIN
select count(*) INTO v_count from MYUSE200 where username1=p_username1 and password1=p_password1;
IF v_count>0 THEN
v_count:=v_count+0;
ELSE
v_count:=0;
END IF;
END;
/
```

codebehind

```
protected void button1_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(strConnString);


        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("p_myuse200",conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        OracleParameter username1 = new OracleParameter("p_username1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
        username1.Value = textbox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(username1);

        OracleParameter password1 = new OracleParameter("p_password1 ", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 45);
        password1.Value = textbox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(password1);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("v_count", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 30);
        cmd.Parameters["v_count"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


             Int32 results = 0;

          //results = (Int32)cmd.Parameters["v_count"].Value;

           try
            {
                results = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["values"].Value);
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
               //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (results > 0)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("http://www.facebook.com");
                }
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             Response.Redirect("http://www.gmail.com");
            }
}
}
```

I'm unable to login any suggestions, both in case of stored procedure and codebehind.
results>0 is not getting the current value count=1 and results should be 1 but it is always zero and else block is executing,,,

Comment: Please consider changing the tags of your question.

Comment: Is this in Oracle? Please add a tag. Remember Oracle is case sensitive. Can you clarify: does the stored procedure return expected results or not? If not, then the 'codebehind' is totally irrelevant in this case and you should remove it.

Comment: use a 'using' block around your connection. If an exception is being thrown by your executescalar, you're connection is not being closed

Comment: i dont know if there is any error in stored procedure but it should v_count=1>0 so in code behind it should be executed,,,,as >0 but it is not happening,,,@Nick.McDermaid

Comment: You need to Unit Test. Work out whether your SP is working properly. No? Fix the stored procedure. Yes? Fix the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. You should get the results from the query like this:

```
var results = (int) ExecuteScalar();
```